# plsql procedures with cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure, cursors

[image]

for the firsrt part using ORACLE  PLsql
**Procedure 2:** 
for every book written by author given by last name change all ISBN OF HIS BOOKS FOR WHAT IS A SECOND PARAMETER OF PROCEDURE??

how can I get and change ISBN of the book?

```
set serveroutput on
create or replace procedure changeISBN(Last_Name varchar(100),ISBN int)
no_book exception;
no_author exception;
cursor c1 is 
select *  from book where book.idAuthor= Auhtor.idAuthor and Author.LastName =Last_Name;
if
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Can you run the SELECT standalone?

Comment: Select statement is invalid you are using columns from Author but not invoking the Author table - you need a join

Comment: You don't need a (slow and inefficient) cursor or even PL/SQL for this.

Comment: 'FOR WHAT IS A SECOND PARAMETER OF PROCEDURE??' - so you can tell the procedure what you want to set the isbn to.

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want to keep cursor in your code, I guess you need below -

```
create or replace procedure changeISBN(P_Last_Name varchar2
                                      ,P_ISBN number
                                      ,P_message out varchar2)
V_AUTHOR Auhtor%idAuthor;
CURSOR C_AUTHOR(Last_Name varchar2)
IS
    SELECT idAuthor
    FROM Auhtor
    WHERE LastName = Last_Name;
Begin
    OPEN C1(P_Last_Name);
    LOOP
        FETCH C_AUTHOR INTO V_AUTHOR;
        UPDATE book
        SET ISBN = P_ISBN
        WHERE book.idAuthor = V_AUTHOR;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE C1;
    P_message := 'Successfully Updated';
EXCEPTION
     when others then
             P_message := 'Update Failure';
END;
```

Comment: but I should contain cursors